# Простая выборка MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

1. Есть таблица, в ней столбец со значениями валют "USD", "RUR", "EUR" и другими валютами.
2. В php поступает POST с выборкой валют, где каждой валюте которую нужно выбрать присваивается либо true либо false; Например:

```html
<?
$usd = $_POST['usd']; (true)
$rur = $_POST['rur']; (false)
$rur = $_POST['eur']; (true)
?>
```

3. Как сделать запрос в базу что бы выбрать usd и eur?

То что первое приходит на ум. Через php и условия сделать разные запросы. Как можно по другому?

Comment: использовать конструкцию `IN` в запросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обширный набор функций работы с массивами делает решение этой задачи в части обработки входных параметров весьма кратким.
 Со стороны БД у вас есть инструкция `IN`, поэтому конечная цель работы - написание запроса вида `WHERE currency IN ('usd', 'eur')`.
Промежуточный слой - инстурментарий доступа к БД (`PDO`, `mysqli`) имеют функционал передачи параметров и использования *плейсхолдеров*.

Таким образом, вам необходимо сформировать запрос вида

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE currency IN (?, ?)
```

и выполнить его  передав параметры `['usd', 'eur']`.

Допустим, вот ваш приходящий `$_POST` и возможные названия валют выглядят так:

```
$POST = [ 'eur' => true, 'usd' => true, 'rur' => false, 'gbp' => false ];
$accept = ['eur', 'usd', 'rur' ];
```

Тогда чтобы получить только ключи со значениями `true`, можно использовать следующий подход:

```
$filter = array_filter(array_intersect($POST, array_flip($accept)));
```

Формируем строку плейсхолдеров, составляем запрос, и выполняем его

```
$phs = array_fill(1, count($filter), '?');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE currency IN (".implode(',', $phs).")";
$conn->execute($sql, array_keys($filter));
```